# change Android phone default calculator

Tags: android

First, I very sorry if my English is not good enough.

My android phone have a very simple calculator.
 i want to use my calculator android app in my phone instead of default calculator in my phone.
What can i do to my calculator run as default calculator app in phone??

i find this code in a site:

```
<category name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

but how define an app(Example: Calculator) for this code?

hint: Like launchers, That you install it on your phone you can use that as default launcher.

Comment: You can't override the launcher action of the default calculator. Just write your app. Launch your app instead of the default.

Comment: for Contact app,how?

Answer (score 1):

The calculator that shows up in your Android launcher is just the icon of an app that came pre-installed with the phone.

You can write your own calculator app and another icon will be shown in the launcher, just tap that one to open the custom calculator.

Unlike browsers or cameras, where [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) are used to list certain tasks that apps can ask another app to do for them (open a webpage, take a picture, ...), there is no need for other apps to call the calculator app to do something for them. As such, a calculator app sets no such intents.